# How to set Background image that cant be repeated

Tags: html, css, background-image, dreamweaver, photoshop

While doing `PSD to html` i have got a `background image that  cant be set to repeat  using  css repeat   property because images is not consistent   like  a pattern` , its  like a full page width/ height image that will require me to set its width height same as page without repeating it , so how do i get it  in a way that images is also loaded as background and site  speed is also not disturbed  , Please help me with , should i simply set its background image for `container div ?` or somethig else ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CSS property for that:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /*Your image here*/
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Check this link for more information about that :

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

The compatibility is here:

http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

PD: don't forget the prefixes vendors